# How to run the JS with on() function with Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery, html

In the Calendar with Add button, after the JS Calendar starts completely, the HTML below appears and I would like to run my JS with `AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView` attribute. However, it doesn't work at all.

Otherwise, is there any solution for my problem that I need to make sure that I can use the `AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView` attribute to run my JS?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView">
    <div class="ms-acal-header">
    <div>
        <table class="ms-acal-month">
        </table>
        <div class="ms-acal-vlink">
            <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Add" evtid="new_item">
                    <img border="0" src="/_layouts/images/caladd.gif">Add</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div></div></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView div div table" ).on( "click", function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

or

```
$( "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView" ).on( "click", '.ms-acal-vlink' , function() {
    var abc = $("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"] [evtid="new_item"]').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).attr('href', 'http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Make sure your HTML is rendered before the JS is executed. Try using $( document ).ready or load function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before. The problem is that the `#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView` is empty when the body loads, then its content is rendered asynchronously.

You need to attach the on click handler function to some outer container that you know it's there when the body loads.
This is how I did it:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("spReady");

function spReady() {
  $('.s4-ba').on('click', '.ms-acal-item a', function(){ 
     console.log('clicked');  
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I am sure that it works very well because I got the same idea with you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, please let me know if it doesn't work with your SharePoint or anything goes wrong :-).

```
$(document).on("click", "#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView .ms-acal-vlink", function () {
        var find_aTag = $(("#AsynchronousViewDefault_CalendarView").find('a[title="Add"]'));
        find_aTag.attr("href", "http://share/Lists/Calendar.aspx?P=P1");
    });
```